# Configuring MvcMiniProfiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, profiling, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to configure mvc miniprofiler with my asp.net mvc 3 application. The problem is that I can't access MiniProfiler class in my views (I'm using webforms viewengine). I have tried a few things

- Added namespace under page directive in web.config (main web.config)
- Added namespace under page directive in web.config (web.config in views folder)
- import namespace in view

But when I write

```
<%var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;%>
```

in my view it announces that MiniProfiler does not exist in current context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include the proper namespace in your views:

```
<% var profiler = MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.Current; %>
```

Comment: @Darin i wrote something like <add namespace="MvcMiniProfiler" /> in web.config and also writing fully qualified name does not work either. it refuses to recognize the namespace. i installed mvcprofiler using nuget if it matters

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid, in which web.config you write this? If you are using the WebForms view engine this should be done in the `<pages>` section of section main web.config and not the one in `~/Views`. I have just tested this and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Darin i have it in main web.config too but it does not work for me. what i find strange is that i can't even access it using fully qualified name as you mentioned in your answer

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid, well that's very strange indeed. Do you have the `MvcMiniProfiler` assembly referenced in your web project? Also don't be fooled if Visual Studio underlines it as error (VS designer can be crappy sometimes), try running the site and see if it works.

Comment: @Darin yes its present in references an working fine in my controllers and other places just views are creating problem

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid, wow, I don't know. It's really strange what you are describing as I have just tested it in a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the WebForms view engine, installed the `MvcMiniProfiler` NuGet and wrote this code in my view and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: @Darin it VS designer and this time it behaved f***ing crappy. thanks for the valuable input